# RelativeLayout: wrap_content is not respected

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

Why the RelativeLayout doesn't wrap content? If I remove the last view which aligns to the bottom parent, it works...

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="3dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/persistent_buttons_area_height"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp">

        <com.xxx.ui.presentation.VerticalNestedScrollview
            android:id="@+id/scroll_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="11dp"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:overScrollMode="never">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:id="@+id/description"
                style="@style/PresentationDescription"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal" />

        </com.xxx.ui.presentation.VerticalNestedScrollview>

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/keyline_1"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="@drawable/list_top_gradient_dark"/>

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/keyline_1"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="@drawable/list_bottom_gradient_dark"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

The current result is (in red rectangle is the RelativeLayout):

[image]

So can I have a wrap content properly for this RelativeLayout?

Thank you very much guys!

Answer (score 0):

How it could be, because you are using `View` with `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"`, Now what it does is that align that view to the bottom of the relative layout, now `RelativeLayout` height is `wrap_content` this won't work because `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` which force relative layout to use as much space is available.

So Possible solution can be:
add `android:layout_below="@+id/scroll_view"` and remove `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` from View which is at bottom of the screen.

Comment: thanks for your reply. Therefor this view is not under scrollview but it's an overlay at the scrollview bottom, so your proposition is not correct for my case.